# Is WD40 a Newtonian liquid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, non-newtonian-fluids

Reading the [technical specifications](https://www.datocms-assets.com/10845/1562170737-wd-40-technical-data-sheet8-21-17.pdf) of WD40 it says that it has a quite **high kinematic viscosity** (i.e. very little viscous fluid) of 2.8 cST @38C. However reading through its revealed trade secret compound [composition](https://web.archive.org/web/20140119014037/http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/magazine/17-05/st_whatsinside) I've discovered that there are a lot of different material on the mix that could contribute potentially towards rather a non-Newtonian fluid characteristics therefore making this kinematic high value given of viscosity apparent.

Also here is an interesting article that shows how an alkane hydrocarbon when combined with water can exhibit non-Newtonian fluid dynamics: [Article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272564/1-s2.0-S0021979700X03931/1-s2.0-0021979776902125/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIASOjWqh1968WtTkjDgEG%2BNO9e6PfK8NmoTWViba2kHlAiA0ENru1m4DVEMq0hlrhg0rYBdYtGnke%2FE51dtO4qDdVyqDBAit%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMXvoeOahxqJCkaDJ2KtcDmn0hq0pQd%2FvGzZMRxDy59OiK%2BIB7Ft7fUFM0%2BcqVx%2FrAuFb6I0qoE9GxWdZhMRDC6EE%2BokNnKs3oXQOtV7W4qHTEf7RybgM%2BOogPrCVMXhI69Ht6QkSxScmrmDdQOBMv2Dl8%2FN5KXUo1jBXJXNVmHGcdzrXqAmtTsjCfa5qIHTZwaaBKlxBzREK4%2BC%2BuzG19pt2Fk0qxmE0RZiGo3hTVdUQkU%2FAG29%2FmWZP%2B%2F7GDfptkyLFSD4YEPA3mpLH4Puo1cgOJObLXO4P%2Fqvs0Vo3347yKo%2B14FbJuNSggIlJwK%2FwQzPonb%2BtOJyAiMuWTryoxWC0B0xmPtxsXzHUwOg4tI6PL%2Bw8orenQp6AYAjRKNtvfH16qIn4DxShWPw5JEpqaHm3DTRZVwJq8SiPEn8oBXOtQSTh0zCUm6BavlDOHzVB%2FDW%2BzOwjkWqun8kxJyLFEBcPYkXu9UEshYdPcMUs23oUwt8v58BOXUNX34jzrKqQ8jecLfXUtReXC7XFlhjYmfnyMO%2B76otkILX82JNch3w8HUnbCqH1RQfp4H7wZiMJV9oJbEyhT%2BhtMrI0yT%2FCbSqiwVHkANce8POkuqY7NxNiSxMzEBVbaNyppuW%2BZG%2Bg%2FGYt2ffZdMMOFxogGOqYBsgdVL%2FiqaMnLXJlGOPw8Lgyw9Bz2XxYr5pAEKeqiXYz9j8zgmlemcrKrQ37%2FYyEmjD%2FNfRoLQYpwsab0fZ5YgVkWsmv0dG%2FxVzsWR%2FmtTvJD97w0rzx3Ro%2FNwmdX0ESLDNr65o%2FnohMuxOKvxJyH6gi1t21YUdsSkGPVU%2FkpbxrYfjiEDwfSOZm%2Fvehet0T2xaHuDbWpG0iSiu9ALi7nMMpblJvqqg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210809T212314Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3V2EZINI%2F20210809%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=2de9fab80f3062d97f320e5dc5aff9a2d6c9081a133f00760a13e2e388bbe52f&hash=28c0e19757cbf2919af3a36d69f68b2c12dc2eb48f0e8d6224dec0ae8b52eb25&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021979776902125&tid=spdf-230e40fd-08c1-4400-aeff-64aa87a85aaa&sid=60e12740625e744288799399959c08acd95egxrqb&type=client)

Comment: *I've discovered that there are a lot of different material on the mix that could contribute potentially towards rather a non-Newtonian fluid characteristics* Like which ones? There are no ingredients in there that could give rise to non-Newtonian behaviour. Stuff that **does exhibit  non-Newtonian behaviour** is of much, much higher molecular weight, like oligomers or polymers. But there are non of these present...

Comment: Something is off here about the 2.8 cSt  figure they are giving in their data sheet. For example pure benzene at the same temperature 38C has a kinematic viscosity of only 0.592 cSt! https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/benzene-benzol-dynamic-kinematic-viscosity-temperature-d_2073.html

Comment: Datasheets aren't scientific docs, errors do occurr in them. WD40 is very thin (like benzene). And it clearly isn't a non-Newtonian liquid.

Comment: I have updated the "composition" link of WD-40 in the question.

Comment: *"Rheological properties of a concentrated surfactant system were determined. Flow curves for a fluid composed of an alkylbenzene sulfonate, hydrocarbon, water, and cosurfactant were obtained as a function of the amount of water added to the system. All fluids were optically clear and phase stable. Compositions that can be classified as oil-external microemulsions were found to exhibit Newtonian flow behavior. Non-Newtonian flow was observed for those compositions that were in the oil-external to water-external transition region."* Ctd.

Comment: That's quite a bit more complicated than your "an alkane hydrocarbon when combined with water"